Is it allowed to give all of one's reputation points away via bounty?
If a person wants to leave, would they be able to give away loads or all of their points through bounties (reward existing answer mainly), or would that be flagged as some sort of offense and shut down?

Would this make the SE sites better?

If it's to reward a single user, it'd be frowned upon, probably, but I think it's fine otherwise...

If it isn’t fraud it isn’t fraud. Dont do fraud

@KevinB fraud is bad.
